# Does PostgreSQL have a way of creating metadata about the data in a particular table?

Tags: postgresql

I'm dealing with a lot of unique data that has the same type of columns, but each group of rows have different attributes about them and I'm trying to see if PostgreSQL has a way of storing metadata about groups of rows in a database or if I would be better off adding custom columns to my current list of columns to track these different attributes. Microsoft Excel for instance has a way you can merge multiple columns into a super-column to group multiple columns into one, but I don't know how this would translate over to a PostgreSQL database. Thoughts anyone?

Right, can't upload files. Hope this turns out well.

```
Section 1 | Section 2 | Section 3
=================================
Num1|Num2 | Num1|Num2 | Num1|Num2
=================================
132 | 163 | 334 | 1345| 343 | 433
......
......
......
```

Comment: You are talking "Groups of rows" and then you talk about "Groups of columns". Also this sounds like your schema is all over the place and possibly poorly normalized. A table is just a table and that's that. You can "Group" records while querying and aggregating using an `OVER()` clause in a window function, but I'm not sure that's what you are after here. Can you share some sample data to help us better understand what you are talking about?

Comment: Sure. It may take some time though.

Comment: Well... even just a small sample/example that shows what you are talking about "Groups of rows being the same and different from a another group" That doesn't make too much sense from an RDBMS standpoint but it does a bit from an Excel standpoint. It would be helpful to be able to visualize that though like `Dog; Cat; Horse; Tomato; Green Bean; Carrot` all in the same column, but two groups?

Comment: See above. I don't know what you'd call the Sections. Supercolumns?

Comment: That does help. I feel like this is just poorly normalized data. Two tables would be more appropriate (possibly) but the entire table layout is really antithetical to the "Relational" aspect of an RDBMS.

Comment: In Excel merged cells are the work of satan, and RDBMS just don't work like this. A column is a column and that's it.

Comment: Like the response Rik. I may go with a 'special' column then. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps a table like `Section | num1 | num2` would make the most sense here (looking at this again). A record in that table would be `1 | 132 | 163`.  This would make a bit more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a "super group" of columns (In SQL in general, not just postgreSQL), the easiest approach is to use multiple tables.
Example:

Person table can have columns of 
person_ID, first_name, last_name

employee table can have columns of
person_id, department, manager_person_id, salary

customer table can have columns of
person_id, addr, city, state, zip

That way, you can join them together to do whatever you like..

Example:

```
 select *
 from person p
 left outer join student s on s.person_id=p.person_id
 left outer join employee e on e.person_id=p.person_id
```

Or any variation, while separating the data into different types and PERHAPS save a little disk space in the process (example if most "people" are "customers", they don't need a bunch of employee data floating around or have nullable columns)

That's how I normally handle this type of situation, but without a practical example, it's hard to say what's best in your scenario.